# WP ACF: hide/display terms of taxonomy on conditional logic

Tags: wordpress, forms, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

Using ACF in Wordpress, my form has  ACF taxonomy field (based on a custom taxonomy).
In the ACF taxonomy list, I need to hide or display some specific taxonomy terms depending of what has been previously choosen in the form.
Terms be displayed or hidden would have been set in arrays with ID.

The best would have been a plugin that allows in ACF to add manually the terms but it does no exist.

Thanks for help.

Comment: use a repeater with custom taxonomy https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/custom-taxonomy-in-repeater-field/

Comment: sorry don't see what can do repeaters in this case...

Comment: 1. if you are sending a form, you GET_POST the value on next page and loop your taxonomy to apply show/hide
   |  2. if the selection is within the form before it is sent, then either you use JS to add/remove a show/hide css class or do it directly with JS
   |  You'd use repeater to auto populate all the taxonomies defined in ACF, with an ID or a class and then simply show/hide. 
   |  You can use WP to add taxonomies from front end using aJax if you want, finally you can look into this: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/manage-taxonomy-terms-on-the-front-end/